# Doubling system clock freq doesn't halve simulated time?

Tags: gem5

I am playing in the SE mode, with script 'GEM5_PATH/configs/learning_gem5/part2/simple_memobj.py', where I altered frequencies between:

```
# Set the clock fequency of the system (and all of its children)
system.clk_domain = SrcClockDomain()
system.clk_domain.clock = **'1GHz'**
```

and

```
# Set the clock fequency of the system (and all of its children)
system.clk_domain = SrcClockDomain()
system.clk_domain.clock = **'2GHz'**
```

I read the first line from "stats.txt" about the sim_seconds, 1GHz takes 0.000508s, while 2GHz takes 0.000459s, which is not halved as overall system frequency is doubled. Any hints about the reason? Any other configs needed to make it as desired?

The command is:
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part2/simple_memobj.py

The benchmark is:
'tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello'

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is good to also link to the corresponding mailing list thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15912.html

Comment: Thanks for reminder, @Ciro. I will stick to the gem5-users thread.